# What is the order of growth of this function?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm new to algorithm and big 0. What is the order of growth of this function?

I do a println and f(10) runs 15 times. f(20) runs 31 times.

It looks to me like `log(N)*N/2`. So it is `logarithmic` or `linearithmic`?

```
   static long f (long N) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
            for (long j = 0; j < i; j++)
                sum++;
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Is this homework? Tell us how you reason it and what your method for reasoning it out is and we'll tell you if how you're approaching the problem is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime is O(n). To see this, note that the inner loop runs 1 time on the first iteration, 2 times on the next iteration, 4 times on the next iteration, and more generally 2<sup>i</sup> times on the 2<sup>i</sup>th iteration. The outer loop stops after lg n iterations because it keeps doubling, so the total work done is

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>lg n</sup>

This is the [sum of a geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) and works out to 2<sup>lg n + 1</sup> - 1 = 2 · 2<sup>lg n</sup> - 1 = 2n - 1 = O(n).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop j counts i times -> max is n

Outter loop counts from 0 to n, multiplying by 2 each time, so it's lgn times.

So total is o(nlgn)

Comment: This is a correct bound, but it's not tight. See my answer for a tighter bound.

Comment: inner loop is not really O(n) is it? it's more like N of Log(N) from the outter loop?

Comment: @user3570795 that's right. It's the upper bound that counts, thus N.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding formally, you obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

O(2^lgn) should be the complexity.growth of exponential function is more than a linear funtion.Hence 2.2^lgn=O(2^lgn) instead of O(n)